# Random letters missing on Android interface inside of vitual device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Does anyone know what can cause the following? It was working earlier but something seems to have happened to cause random letters to be missing on the Android interface. I have tried this on multiple virtual devices and this is not happening inside of any app I have written (I haven't even gotten to the point where I can install my app).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by selecting "SwiftShader" for "OpenGL ES renderer"

Get to this by clicking "..." > "Settings" > "Advanced"

Other members of my team had to select different values. Possibly because they have different machines. I'll have to do some more investigation on why we have to select different values.